# Grouping lat/lng into grid of 1 km squares

Tags: coordinate-system, coordinates

We have a lot of lat/lng that we would like to group into a grid of ~1 km squares.

1) Grouping lat isn't difficult. That's just grouping them by lat +/- 0.02, i.e. 14.X will be grouped like this:

```
14.00-14.02
14.02-14.04
14.04-14.06
etc.
```

2) Problem is lng, since the length of each lng varies depending on where you are looking.

Does anyone know a formula for converting lng to km that handles the varying length of lng?

I know this is not 100% precise 1 km squares, for it's good enough for our purpose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using Google, approximated length (kilometers) per 1 degree of longitude can be calculated as below. (This sample formula is assuming latitude= 14.02. Please change it as necessary.)

```
(6378000*2*pi*(cos(14.02/180*pi))/360)/1000
```

[image]
[image]

---

If you prefer Excel

```
A1:    14.02
B1:    = (6378000 * 2 * PI() * COS(A1/180*PI()) / 360) / 1000
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Then I just need to reverse the formular, so I can get the number of degrees per km for each lng.